# How to differentiate an infinite sum?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Given this function : 
$s (x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} $ , its derivative $c (x)=s' (x) $. How to show that $c'(x)=-s (x) $ ?

This question is related to [Relationship Between Sine as a Series and Sine in Triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230596/relationship-between-sine-as-a-series-and-sine-in-triangles)

Is $c'(x)$ the double of derivative $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} $ ? So I take the derivative of $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} $ to arrive at $c(x)$ and then take derivative of $c(x)$ to arrive at c'(x) ?

Comment: Related: [See accepted answer for a hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743165/sequences-and-series-of-functions).  Yes, $c^\prime(x)$ is the double derivative of $s(x)=\sin x$.  You just need to take derivatives and then compare the signs of each term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is exactly the idea. 
\begin{align*}
 s(x) =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.
\end{align*}
Hence we have that:
\begin{align*}
 c(x) = s'(x) =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2k+1)x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}.
\end{align*}
Now taking yet another derivative we get:
\begin{align*}
 c'(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2kx^{2k-1}}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{2(k+1)x^{2(k+1)-1}}{(2(k+1))!} \\
 &= - \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = -s(x).
\end{align*}